# how to get all names and date of births from a specific file using java

Tags: java, regex

Hi below is my text file

```
welcome to java training

     program

Name    rtrti*&*
  John

address     india   say^%$7
Date of Birth
11/12/1989
```

I have 100 files like above.The above text is the extracted text from the image files so it is not in order, from this i need to get the names and date of births can you please suggest me how to do this, I am new to this task.

Required output

```
John
11/12/1989
```

I have tried

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Name");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(content);
matcher.find();
```

But I have know idea how to get the next line of matched pattern, I cant not read this file line by line because my need is to store entire text in a single string.

Comment: Reopen this?  He has provided an attempt.

Comment: Try looking for line terminators, like "/r/n" or "/n".

Comment: Ask this as a new question at this point.  It doesn't look like this will be reopened.  With your updates, this is a good valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give a few hints that will get you on track.  Without more details regarding the expected input, it will be difficult to give you a solid solution.  First, I trust that you are already familiar with the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) javadocs. You will need to understand the **Groups and capturing** section. Finally, you can utilize [DOTALL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) mode which will allow the `.` character to match newlines.

To get you started, the following should work to find the name:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
    "(?s)"      + // DOTALL
    ".*"        + // Match anything (to consume everything before 'Name')
    "Name"      + // Match the literal 'Name'
    ".*?"       + // Reluctantly grab everything until...
    "\n"        + // Newline is reached
    "\\s*"      + // Consume leading whitespace
    "(\\S+)"      // Capture at least one non-whitespace character
);
Matcher m = p.matcher(content);

if(m.find()) {
    String name = m.group(1);  // The first capturing group contains "John"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but How can I compare with John because I do not know what value is there, It may have any value

Comment: Right. If you are not familiar with assertions, then that was a little confusing. I have updated that portion of the answer to better help you.